# Problems with UIScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I have such a UIControllerView:

```
--Main View
  --UIScrollview
    --Label 1
    --Label 2
```

I have a short (1 line text) for Label 1, and I have a very long text for Label 2, so I've set for Label 2: **0 lines, sizeToFit()**. Okay, and when I'm running my app in simulator, everything looks okay, but when I'm trying to scroll the screen:

1. There is no scrollbar, while I've not disabled it
2. My long Label 2 is not scrolling fully, it's just bouncing from the bottom of screen

And this code I have:

```
self.labelSecond.text = content //very long content
self.labelSecond.sizeToFit()
```

For UIScrollView I've enabled AutoSizing. Please help, how to make my long label scroll fully, not bounce from the bottom?

[image]

Comment: you don't need to write any codes for scroll, autolayout will do everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your storyboard make a view structure like the below image

[image]

For some reasons, if the image is not shown, I have described what the image says below:

Inside your `ScrollView` add a `view` with the height of your `scrollView` and set the constraint for `top` `bottom` `leading` and `trailing`, and make the view `Horizontally` centre.

Then add your two labels inside the view. and for the first label set contraints as `top`, `leading` and `trailing`. For the second label set contraints for four sides. Make the label's `line number` 0 and `line breaking` as `Word Wrap`. This will solve your problem. You do not have to write any codes.

For your better understanding, I have created a demo project and uploaded it [here](https://ufile.io/6cbfq).

For any doubts or query leave a comment, I will try to make that clear.

Comment: Peter, thank you very very much!!1 Thank you for your detailed response!!

Comment: Happy coding! We are always here for one another. One up vote will be appreciated :P Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You have to add one more `UIView` after `UIScrollView`. so Your flow of your screen should look like  below

```
--Main View
  --UIScrollview
    --Content View
       --Label 1
       --Label 2
```

[image: Look at this image]

**Note:- Don't forget to give fixed height to Content View**

Comment: Container View is name of UIView

Comment: At first, thank you for your respond, sir! I've added UIView, added AutoResizing for it, but it's still not scrolling to down.

Comment: And there is no scrollbars yet

Comment: Have you given fix height to container view?

Comment: Yes, fixed width 375 and height 554 by visual drag resizing

Comment: width should have same as Main View's width

Comment: They're both 375

Comment: Can you include document outline's screenshot in your question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156446/discussion-between-vishalpethani-and-mr-jo).